# How to know a thread finished in Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am writing a Chinese Chess game with AI in Cocos2d-x. When I touch the board, I want to start a thread that runs the AI and I need to know when this thread finishes. How can I send a message to the main thread?

Comment: I  want to know when the thread finish, then post message to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d-x framework is not multi-threading by default. if you want to use your own, you need to learn how to create and join and detect the mutex etc using pthread by yourself.